# How fast would the people of an alternate earth progress technology/medicine wise without religion?

Tags: alternate-history, technological-development, alternate-earth

One of the main themes of my series is an infinite multiverse, and one of the main characters was born on an earth where religion never existed. The humans of this world except for my MC do not and can not feel anger or hate. They can feel frustrated but not anger or any emotion like it.

So I've been having trouble. How fast would a society advance in technology and medicine? Would it be too much of a stretch if they progressed every century or so? These humans in my story are not like most, they and the humans in a universe next to them(that being us) are the genetic descendants of twin gods that gave up their physical bodies to create a breed of humans who would one day receive a gift from beings that are known for being the most powerful in the known multiverse. A gift that would hasten and vastly improve their evolution.

I know how advanced they are in the MC's lifetime. 
the year on his earth is 1954(I picked this year because of it being an alternate earth where Alan Turing is alive and the current president of the U.N.A), his America is known as the United Nations of America. There is no poverty, diseases, crime, and the most of the time the only reason people die is that they died of old age, which is around 200 to 400 years. Also, most of the planets in their solar system have been terraformed. In 15 years they will discover interstellar travel.

I'd appreciate any help given. :D

Comment: Hi and welcome. You seem to have answered the question in the title, and there is no question in the body. What exactly is that you want us to answer? Also "1954" sounds a lot like a religious-referenced date.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding.SE! Questions like this are generally considered too broad, which would explain the downvotes and close votes you're getting. Personally, I feel like you're vastly overestimating how much society would progress if religion didn't exist, but that's just me.

Comment: Hello and thank you. It may be far-fetched, but it's how this Earth went in my head. I don't mean to offend by any of it.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure how 95% of the content of this question has anything to do with having or not having a religion. For example, in 1954 there was an officially atheist country on earth (the USSR) and homosexuality was [just as illegal there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGBT_history_in_Russia#LGBT_history_post-Stalin:_1953.E2.80.931991) as it was at the time in the UK.

Comment: @T.E.D. Homosexuality is not a factor in this, it's only about how a smarter human civilization would advance without religion.

Comment: @SojournHollow - If it isn't a factor why did you bring Alan Turing (who was effectively killed due to his prosecution for homosexuality) being alive into it? I'm really confused now.

Comment: @SojournHollow Now that you make the humans smarter, then the question becomes even more broad.

Comment: @T.E.D. Because it is an alternate earth where this Alan Turing is not gay nor is he autistic.

Comment: @SojournHollow - So he's a completely different guy, who just happens to also be named "Alan Turing"? Seriously, if it doesn't have (in your mind) anything to do with your question about religion, I'd recommend removing it from the question.

Comment: If this wasn't opinion-based before, then adding "In your mind" to the question has *definitely* made it too opinion-based, since opinions are now what you're outright asking for.

Comment: Religion, in most cultures seems to be one of the first stepping stones to a more organised and objective knowledge of the world. The initial concept of a god, or gods, especially a great creator, introduces the idea that there is some rationale behind how the world is and how the world works. In time, this becomes science, but it cannot start out as science.

Answer (score 5):

### Counter-intuitively, Technology would advance more slowly

As it would happen, Religion and War are some of the most powerful forces contributing to human technological advancement. For instance, Egyptian and Mesopotamian religion where some of the earliest contributors to architecture in the form of the Pyramids and Ziggurats. Egyptian religion also gave us the first Semitic scripts, which evolved into Arabic, Greek, Hebrew, Latin, etc. Hinduism, Jainism, and Buddhism where collectively responsible for the spark of the Golden age of India, which gave the world, among other things, the incorrectly named arabic numerals, damascus steel, and surgical tools. The Islamic golden age gave us algebra, public hospitals, and some of the earliest pharmacies.

War, I would argue, has had the greatest influence on Human technological advancement. Period. War gave humanity some of the first logistics system, advancements in metallurgy, chemistry, physics, epidemiology, it gave us the radio, microwaves, synthetic rubber, blood banks, plastic surgery, nuclear power, ultrasounds, rocketry, the internet. The fastest periods of advancement in human history come either during, or soon after war. Governments are willing to alter their entire economies to produce weapons of war and fund their research, without war, an incentive its equal does not exist.   ***Without conflict, Solutions are not Needed***

Answer (score 3):

**Born of religion**

Religion is mostly intertwined with our capacity of understand the things that are around us. Some believe that is genetic, causality or even a trait that affect some people more than others (God gene).

**Science**

Fire, dying, lighting, the sun, and most things that happend all around can't be simply explained, but still the humand mind try to give it a meaning to avoid "the fear of the unknown" in that regard we created explanations to handle this concepts.

In other words science and religion are born for the same capacity of understand the causality of our actions and of most things around us, and the need to feel comfortable and safe within our world.

Which means that with enough intelligence, curiosity and necessity, religion and science would occur naturally.

**Medicine**

In a world where you don't have diseases, gunshots, wars, hunger or epidemics probably the evolution of medicine would being halted mostly completly. There is no need of doctors or research if people don't fall ill.

Comment: If they die of 'old age' (at whatever age) there still might be something for medicine to work on.

Answer (score 1):

Religion is not (usually) neutral in Science/Technology development, but different religions may have different effects, even for quite "similar" religions.

Christianity is often pointed out as a large hamper for everything "material", and that has surely been true throughout the Dark Ages.

Different "flavors" of Islam produced both [al-Khwarizmi](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_ibn_Musa_al-Khwarizmi), whose name is encoded in the word "algorithm" (reason is kind of funny: it seems a repeated phrase in medieval translations often explained a process starting with: "alkwrizmi says..." so the mathematician became synonym of process itself) and Caliph Umar who (legend narrates) ordered [destruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destruction_of_the_Library_of_Alexandria) of Alexandria Library saying: "If those books are in agreement with the Quran, we have no need of them; and if these are opposed to the Quran, destroy them."

Ancient polytheisms never were a stop for scientific development, neither in Greece nor in India.

While certain (specific!) flavors of monotheism can be blamed to have been a brake on scientific advance and technology (mainly insisting on importance of afterlife) it is unproven atheism is of any help.

Comment: No, that was [not at all](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/882/is-there-any-evidence-that-the-catholic-church-slowed-innovation-during-the-midd/2433#2433) "surely true" during the Dark Ages. Arguably if not for the monasteries, knowledge in Europe would have backslid far further than it did.

Comment: @T.E.D.: are you saying that, since about 1% of population preserved a bit of knowledge (mainly practical) about a few techniques this is an adequate compensation for the remaining 99% actively destroying whatever was not "doctrinal"? If we have *any* knowledge of ancient thinkers (beside the few "sanctioned" by Church) is through Arabs. (I am unfair: some tomes were recovered because monks weren't very dedicated when abrading them with pumice to write about the life of some Saint)

Comment: You can read the answers on the other end of that History SE link I posted if you are honestly interested in the details.

Comment: @T.E.D.; I read th whole thread, but I do not agree. It would be a bit too long to explain in a comment, though. Rome influence is double-sided: they were interested in engineering (and they did quite a few interesting feats there), but they were *not* interested in theoretical speculation and thus a lot of good work went lost even before Constantin. An interesting reading is [The Forgotten Revolution](http://www.springer.com/it/book/9783540200680). Later Church worked hard to suppress any deviation from doctrine, as testified by Galileo, Copernicus, Bruno and countless others burnt at stake.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can justify any outcome you might need.

- Superstitious explanations for natural phenomena can slow research, as innovative thinkers get burned at the stake.
- Systematic debate and interpretation of religious texts might train academic thinking ([hermeneutics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermeneutics)), this paves the way to the scientific methods.
- Emotions like anger and hate might cause wars, and wars can accelerate technological development *if they don't destroy the industrial base*.
- Anger that a beloved relative died from an "incurable" disease might push medical research.